# Iterating over PowerShell $input

Tags: powershell, foreach, comobject

I'm getting some strange behaviour (as in non-deterministic) when passing file items into a function and then using $input in a foreach loop.

I'm calling my function like this...

```
get-childitem Stuff | Create-Zip C:\Stuff.zip
```

where "Stuff" contains a bunch of folders that contain directories and sub-directories.  The problem is that, on repeated runs, some of the top level directories don't get copied, regardless of whether or not they are empty.

The function is almost a direct copy of the one at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/12/compress-files-with-windows-powershell-then-package-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget.aspx

```
function Create-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfile)
    set-content $zipfile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfile).IsReadOnly = $false  

    $shellApplication = new-object -comObject Shell.Application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfile)

    foreach($item in $input)
    { 
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($item.FullName)
        Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be with the Start-Sleep line - if I omit this entirely, the zip file is empty... if I increase it to 10 seconds, the zip file is usually full.  Why is this, and is there a better way to write this without depending on a sleep value?

Answer (score 0):

`$input` should be evaluated in the context of a `process {}` scriptblock e.g.:

```
function Create-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfile)
     set-content $zipfile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
     (dir $zipfile).IsReadOnly = $false 

    $shellApplication = new-object -comObject Shell.Application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfile)

    process {
        foreach($item in $input)
        { 
            $zipPackage.CopyHere($item.FullName)
            Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
        }
    }
}
```

However if you're using PowerShell V2, this is a better way to pass pipeline input that relates to files (string paths, FileInfo, etc):

```
function Verb-Noun
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path")]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="Path", 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Path to ...")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        $Path,

        [Alias("PSPath")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="LiteralPath", 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Path to ...")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        $LiteralPath
    )

    Begin { Set-StrictMode -Version latest }

    Process {
        if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Path")
        {
            # In the -Path (non-literal) case we may need to resolve a wildcarded path
            $resolvedPaths = @($Path | Resolve-Path | Convert-Path)
        }
        else 
        {
            # Must be -LiteralPath
            $resolvedPaths = @($LiteralPath | Convert-Path)
        }

        foreach ($rpath in $resolvedPaths) 
        {
            Write-Verbose "Processing $rpath"
            # ... Do something with the raw, resolved $rpath here ...
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that ParseName returns null while item is beeing processed so you can use this code:

```
function Create-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfile)
         set-content $zipfile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
         (dir $zipfile).IsReadOnly = $false 

    $shellApplication = new-object -comObject Shell.Application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfile)

    foreach($item in $input)
    { 
             $zipPackage.CopyHere($item.FullName)
             do {
                $i = $zipPackage.ParseName($item.Name)
                Start-Sleep -milliseconds 10
            } while ($i -eq $null)
    }
}
```

It works here without a problem, even without Start-Sleep which is there just not to burn out CPU.